# RxJava: return random objects from Observable correctly

Tags: java, rx-java

My task is to produce given amount of random object (shapes — circles or squares) in Producer, print them to console and than use them in Consumer. For generating random objects I use method `getShape` in abstract class `Shape` and then, while creating of Observable, I use `defer()` for getting each time new object.

For printing objects I tried to use `doOnNext`:

```
Observable<Shape> produceShapes(int amount) {
        System.out.println("Produced following shapes:");
        return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(Shape.getShape()))
                .doOnNext(System.out::print)
                .repeat(amount);
    }
```

Consumer method is usual `Observable.just(new Producer().produceShapes(10))...`

The problem is that `defer()` works twice — while printing shapes and while requesting them by Consumer, so Consumer becomes different shapes.

EDIT: I tried to remove `.doOnNext(System.out::print)` and print the objects in `getShape()` method, before giving it to Producer, but Consumer still becomes different shapes.

How can it be solved? How can I create shapes, print them and give the same shapes to Consumer?

Comment: What happens if you remove the defer call? Will the just call be repeated or will it only be called once?

Comment: It will be repeated. The shape object will be created only once and returned on every call.

Comment: That's what I thought :-/ luckily koperko knows his rxjava better :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand, why do you want to use defer. Defer operator creates new observable for every subscriber. If you just want *amount*-number of shapes, just try this:

```
Observable<Shape> produceShapes(int amount) {
    System.out.println("Produced following shapes:");
    return Observable.range(1, amount)
            .map(index -> Shape.getShape())
            .doOnNext(System.out::print);
}
```